# FIltering dates with VBA autofilter on computers with German regional setting

Tags: vba, date, autofilter, regional-settings

I am trying to filter out specific dates in a table using the autofilter function with the AND operator.

The code below works for users who have their regional settings set to those recommended by Windows (English United States).
For users who have their computers set to German the autofilter returns nothing.

It seems the error happens in the following line from the code snippet below:

```
.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & startDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & endDate
```

I checked if the dates were input in the filter and if they were formatted correctly. That doesn't seem to be the issue. The dates appear only once I have clicked "ok" in the [custom autofilter box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8vkJ.png).

```vb
For t = 1 To timeline
    ''update forecast dates
    Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date

    'for first month only consider second half of month
    If t = 1 Then
        startDate = "15/" & Month(Now) & "/" & Year(Now)
    Else
        startDate = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + t - 1, 1) ' t-1 otherwise the forecast will skip a month
    End If

    endDate = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + t, 0)               

    'filter out relevant data
    With overview.Range("C10")
        .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="Direct"
        .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & startDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & endDate
    End With

    ''put values into liquidity cash in out sheet
    'cash in movement

    liquidity.Cells(inputRow, 6 + t).Value2 = overview.Range("O7").Value2 'value input starts in column 7

    'Drawdowns

    liquidity.Cells((inputRow + 1), 6 + t).Value2 = overview.Range("R7").Value2 'value input starts in column 7
Next t
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is solved. I just needed to convert the dates to doubles in the line causing the problem.

```
.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(startDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(endDate)
```

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/issues-filtering-dates-with-vba-autofilter-on-computers-with-german-regional-setting.1189265/